# Why is the URI of an Azure runbook webhook URI blank

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-runbook

I am using an ARM template to deploy a logic app in a second subscription in Azure which needs to trigger a POST to a webhook URL of a runbook in the first subscription.

I use the full reference to the webhook URL object in the ARM template, but unforuntately although there is no error, the logic app ends up with a blank URI.

The reference to the webhook looks like:

```
"RunbookWebHook": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/----/resourceGroups/RunbookResources/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/RunbookAutomationAccount/webhooks/RunbookWebhook"
    },
```

An example reference to the webhook URI in the logic app:

```
"actions": {
    "Runbook_Webhook": {
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
            "headers": {
            "operationName": "@{triggerBody()['data']['operationName']}",
            "resourceId": "@triggerBody()?['subject']"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "uri":  "[reference(parameters('RunbookWebHook'), '2015-10-31').uri]"
    }
}
```

How can I get the correct URL  for the webhook URI?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a restriction in Azure with regards to the Webhook URL.

In the MicroSoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#webhook-properties

it mentions the URL property (which is actually the `uri` field) and it says:

> URL of the webhook. This is the unique address that a client calls with an HTTP POST to start the runbook linked to the webhook. It's automatically generated when you create the webhook. You can't specify a custom URL.

> The URL contains a security token that allows a third-party system to invoke the runbook with no further authentication. For this reason, you should treat the URL like a password. For security reasons, you can only view the URL in the Azure portal when creating the webhook. Note the URL in a secure location for future use.

So the URL cannot be further retrieved after creation. :(

Comment: do you know if there is a way to get and use it during the creation of the webhook within the same template?

Comment: Yes, you can do that @MoonHorse - I will look to see if I have an example somewhere.